# Update and show the results from column on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have newspage that, besides showing the news, needs to follow the mumber of views. I'm using this query by updating the "hits" column in the database

```
 $q = $dbc->query("UPDATE news SET hits=hits+1 WHERE newsid = '$id'");
```

The problems appers when i want it to show me , on the same page, the number of views catching data  from hits. It's says there is an error.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsid = '$id'";
$newsQuery = $dbc->query($sql);
$news = mysqli_fetch_assoc($newsQuery);


$klik = $news['hits'];
```

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'hits' in C:\xampp\htdocs\HipHop\news-details.php on line 22

My qustion is how can i update and show the results on the "hits" column on the same page ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($news)` show?

Comment: The error message implies that `$news` contains a string, not an array. I suspect you reused the `$news` variable for something else before you assigned `$klik`.

Comment: When i do var_dump($news) everything is ok
["hits"]=> string(3) "641"
I don't reused  the $news because everything else works fine. Problem with this column is because I'm updating and show results on same page. When i fetch result from others coulmns everything else is ok.

Comment: Did you put it right before `$klik = $news['hits'];`?

Comment: Is this code inside a function or loop? Can you post more of the code? PHP doesn't make mistakes like this by itself, you must have code that's corrupting the variable.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. When I fetch the news I put them in the variable $news ($news= $news[‘news’];) and in that way I reuse the same variable. Sometimes I really know how to be stupid. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're not the first, you won't be the last, I've seen this dozens of times.